# MySQL query works on MySQL Workbench but not in Python

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, python-3.10

I'm trying to figure out why the following MySQl Query works in MySQL workbench, but in Python throws the error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column '2022-07-19' in 'where clause'")
```

The Query is:

```
sql_query = """Select *
FROM event tb2 
right JOIN (SELECT users.ContactID, users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.email FROM users WHERE users.ContactID)tb2 ON ContactID = tb2.PresenterID 
WHERE \"2022-07-19\" between tb2.StartDateTime AND tb2.FinishDateTime;"""
It runs correctly in MySQL workbench, but not in Python (without the escape characters around the date).
```

I've also tried the query:

```
sql_query = """Select *
FROM event tb2 
right JOIN (SELECT users.ContactID, users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.email FROM users WHERE users.ContactID)tb2 ON ContactID = tb2.PresenterID 
WHERE tb2.StartDateTime < \"2022-06-19\" AND  tb2.FinishDateTime > \"2022-06-19\" """
```

I'd really appreciate any light you could shine on this issue.

Comment: Remove the \ in your second query. You do 't need to scape anything

Comment: I've done this, but it still gives the same error:
sql_query = """Select *
FROM event tb2
right JOIN (SELECT users.ContactID, users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.email FROM users WHERE users.ContactID)tb2 ON ContactID = tb2.PresenterID
WHERE tb2.StartDateTime < "2022-06-19" AND  tb2.FinishDateTime > "2022-07-19" """
Error: MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column '2022-07-19' in 'where clause'")

Comment: There's no way that `WHERE \"2022-07-19\"` is valid SQL, which is why there IS the error: `"Unknown column '2022-07-19' in 'where clause'"`. There should be a column and an operator before the date value, something like `WHERE dateColumn = '2022-07-19'`. To the dates, you can use single quotes around the date values as an alternative.